# Estimate spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-radius

I would like to compute the kernel of the following matrix.

Let $W \in \mathbb{R}^n$ have only $1$'s on its main diagonal and $w_{i,j} \in (-1,0)$ (open interval) off the main diagonal, so that the columns sum up to $-1$. I would like to show that

$$\dim \ker W = 1$$

If this is not true, I ask for a counterexample.

Idea:

It is clear that $\dim\ker W \geq 1$, since adding for all $i=1,...,n-1$ the $i$-th row to the last row of $W$ kills the last row.

Consider the Minor $W_n$, which is $W$ without the last column and the last row. It is left to show that $W_n$ has $\ker = 0$. Consider the decomposition (set $\tilde W_n = W_n - I_{n-1})$
$W_n = I_{n-1} + \tilde W_n$. Now $W_n x=0$ implies $\tilde W_n x = -x$, e.g., $\tilde W_n$ has eigenvalue $-1$.

So the goal is to show that  $\tilde W_n$ has eigenvalue $-1$. I wanted to estimate the spectral raduius and show that is (in absolute value) strictly smaller $1$. This would finish the proof, but I dont know how to do that

I need help here or a different approach :)

Comment: I think you mean that the sum of the off-diagonal entries in each column is $-1$, so that the entries in each columns sum up to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The minor $W_n$ has diagonal entries $1$, and the sum of the off-diagonal entries in each columns is strictly larger than $-1$ (because deleting the last row of the matrix increases this sum). Then [Gershgorin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) tells you that the eigenvalues of the remaining matrix are all non-zero.

If the off-diagonal entries would allowed to be taken from $[-1,0]$ then
$$
\pmatrix{ 1 & -1 &0&0\\ -1 & 1 &0&0\\ 0&0&1&-1\\0&0&-1&1}
$$
would be a counter-example.

Comment: its not a counter-example... since i asked off-diagonal entires to be not 0 and not -1. However i solved my own question. The answer is to used diagonal dominance of the Minor matrix $W_n$ (kill the last column and last row) to see that $rang$ of $\tilde W$ is at least n-1.

Comment: I did not claim this to be a counterexample...